# Issue with Datetime().Format() in Batch Apex

Tags: apex, batch, datetime, format

```
String myDate = Datetime.now().addDays(14).formatGmt('MM/DD');
System.debug('mydate'+myDate);
```

Works fine when I execute from `Developer console`, today is 24 Jan and it prints `02/07` which is correct.

But when I execute in a `Batch class` it prints `02/38` which is wrong, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the right format for days. From [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> `D` Day in year
>   `d` Day in month

So it sounds like you want to use `MM/dd`.

Comment: Thank you it was found and resolved. I updated it in the salesforce forum already.
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G000000I3IqQAK

Comment: @SachinKumar If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.